# How to get value from jquery each loop when controller returns list

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have list and return from controller and i'm trying to show in a mvc view using jquery each loop function.I can get to list and send to view but when jquery loop start i cannot get index and value.I checked Console and Sources,values are there.

This is my controller codes

```
  public JsonResult electric()
    {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
        string cs = "data source=LNPC;initial catalog=db;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("electrcic_bills", connection);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<analiz> TestList = new List<analiz>();
         analiz electric;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            electric= new analiz();
            electric.jan= Convert.ToDouble(reader["jan"].ToString());
            electric.feb= Convert.ToDouble(reader["feb"].ToString());
            electric.march= Convert.ToDouble(reader["march"].ToString());
            electric.april = Convert.ToDouble(reader["april"].ToString());
            TestList.Add(electric);

        }

        return Json(new { List = TestList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Jquery codes

```
           $("#electric").click(function () {

           $("canvas#myCharts").remove();
           $("#canvas1").append('<canvas id="myCharts" width="200" height="200"></canvas>');
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "/MainController/electric",

               dataType: "json",
               success: function (List) {

                   var data = List.List;
                   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                       alert(data);
                   });

               },
           });
       });
```

With this method i cannot  get value but when i write  electric.push(List.List[0].jan._bills_electric) like this i can get value manualy perfctly.

This my Source codes from browser

Local List:List: Array(1)
0:
jan_bills: null
jan_bills_electric: 135
dec_bills: null
dec_bills_electric: 60

Answer (score 0):

You are using `List` word in your `return Json()` statement. This may be ambiguous for Java.
Try using another name with camel case typography to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript, try to use

```
var data = List["List"];
```

instead of

```
var data = List.List;
```

Comment: that didn't work too loop doesnt work when data comes

Answer (score 0):

Okey i found my answer and where l am wrong.
First- there is nothing wrong in my controller
Second-  in each loop function,my array not only array,it is array in OBJECT.I've found [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-function-examples/) and try  each loop in a each loop and i got my items from jquery loop.

```js
var json = [ 
 { 'red': '#f00' },
 { 'green': '#0f0' },
 { 'blue': '#00f' }
];

$.each(json, function () {
   $.each(this, function (name, value) {
      console.log(name + '=' + value);
   });
});
```